# How to create apklib for a project in android

Tags: android

I have a question that I want to make an apklib file for an facebook sdk. But I don't know how to create that but I need to use Facebook Sdk via Maven Repository, how this can be achieved? Please help me out about this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are familiar with Maven and want to use it, maven-android-plugin has a sample project you can start with, check out LibraryProjects at [here](http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/Samples), you need download the 2.9.0-beta one.